# In Laravel, how do I convert a JSON field's value into that for a javascript parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, fullcalendar

I am having trouble using this JSON from Mysql as a javascript object for full Calendar.

Here is my JSON:

```
    [{
    "dow": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "start": "08:00",
    "end": "18:00"
},
{
    "dow": [ 4, 5 ], 
    "start": "10:00", 
    "end": "16:00" 
}]
```

I need to get it into this format:

```
{

dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],

start: '10:00',
end: '18:00',
}
```

Is it possible? This is my controller so far:

```
    public function get_calendar_data()
{
    $resources = Provider::select('providers.id', 'businessHours' , 'first_name AS title', 'categories.colour AS eventColor')
                            ->join('categories' , 'categories.id' , '=' , 'providers.category_id')
                            ->get();

    $events = Booking::select(DB::raw('bookings.id , provider_id AS resourceId , date_format(start , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s" ) AS start ,
    date_format(end , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s" ) AS end , CONCAT(clients.first_name , " " , 
    clients.last_name) AS title'))
        ->join('clients' , 'clients.id' , '=' , 'bookings.client_id' )
        ->get();
    $final_result = [ 'resources' => $resources , 'events' =>$events ];
    return $final_result;
}
```

and my blade script I cant get it to work in:

```
<script>

$( document ).ready( function(){ // document ready

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        defaultDate: '{!! date("Y-m-d") !!}',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        views: {
            agendaTwoDay: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: { days: 2 },

                // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                groupByResource: true

                //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                //groupByDateAndResource: true
            }
        },

        // uncomment this line to hide the all-day slot
        //allDaySlot: false,
        resources:
            {!! json_encode($calendar['resources'])  !!},
        events:
            {!! json_encode($calendar['events'])  !!},

        select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            console.log(
                'select',
                start.format(),
                end.format(),
                resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
            );
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            console.log(
                'dayClick',
                date.format(),
                resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
            );
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

            var data = {'id' : event.id , 'start' : event.start.format() ,
                'end' : event.end.format() , 'provider_id' : event.resourceId };

            $.ajax({
                type: "Put",
                url: '{{route('booking.update')}}',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){alert('Change has been updated');},
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });


            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }

        },
        eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var data = {'id' : event.id , 'start' : event.start.format() , 'end' : event.end.format() };
            //alert(event.title + " end is now " + event.end.format());

            $.ajax({
                type: "Put",
                url: '{{route('booking.update')}}',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){alert('Change has been updated');},
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            if (!confirm("is this change acceptable?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Any ideas on how to get this decoded correctly? I have tried decoding it in multiple areas to no success.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how those 2 merge at the top

Answer (score 0):

It is coming as a collection.. you would need to convert this to array using toArray() or using toJson() method.
have a look here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray